# Rendering Partial Views: Model Mismatch and DataViewDictionary Issue (Razor Page/ASP.NET CORE)

Tags: asp.net-core, partial-views, razor-pages

Amateur programmer here coming back with some more dumb questions for you wonderful people. Please excuse the ignorance on my part when you review my code, it is likely not as clean as some of you pro's out here would like it to be.

I am doing my best to follow Mr. Scott Allen's awesome ASP.Net core tutorials on the Pluralsight webpage. I have gone through it once successfully, and am now going through it again while adapting it for an app I have been wanting to build. I am stuck on a part of the course (module6, video6) where a razor page listing some SQL data on a basic HTML table, is changed to list each DB record as a partial view. In order to do this, an HTML tag helper is used within a FOREACH loop and is passed a partial layout name and model as parameters. On each iteration, it renders each individual DB record on its own partial view, within the main view. The issue I am running into when executing the app is when loading the main page, and arriving at the foreach loop, on the very first iteration it crashes and gives me an "Unhandled Exception" error. I have done my best below to include all the code snippets you guys will need to analyze, but again excuse my ignorance if there is something missing. Please let me know if there is, and I will include it right away.

**MAIN VIEW-List.cshtml:**

```
@page
@model ListModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Containers";
}
<h1>Containers</h1>
<form method="get">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="search" class="form-control"
                   asp-for="SearchTerm" />
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
                </button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
@foreach (var container in Model.Containers)
    {
        <partial name="_Summary" @model="container"/>
    }
<a asp-page="./Edit" class="btn btn-primary"> Add New</a>
@section footer {
    <div>@Model.Message</div>
}
```

**MAINVIEW-List.cshtml.cs**:

```
namespace FreightPush.Pages.Containers
{
    public class ListModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration config;
        private readonly IContainerData containerData;
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Container> Containers { get; set; }
        [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
        public string SearchTerm { get; set; }
        public ListModel(IConfiguration config, IContainerData containerData)
        {
            this.config = config;
            this.containerData = containerData;
        }
        public void OnGet()
        {
            Message = config["Message"];
            Containers = containerData.GetContainersByNumber(SearchTerm);
        }
    }
}
```

**PARTIALVIEW-_Summary.cshtml:**

```
@using FreightPush.Core
@model Container
<div class="card">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3>Container Number: @Model.Number</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <span>Container Type: @Model.ContainerType</span>
        <span>Client: @Model.Client</span>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
        <a class="btn btn-lg"
           asp-page="./Detail"
           asp-route-containerId="@Model.Id">
            <i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i>
        </a>
        <a class="btn btn-lg"
           asp-page="./Edit"
           asp-route-containerId="@Model.Id">
            <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
        </a>
        <a class="btn btn-lg"
           asp-page="./Delete"
           asp-route-containerId="@Model.Id">
            <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The error I get on the first iter of the FOREACH loop inside list.cshtml:

> *InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type
>   'FreightPush.Pages.Containers.ListModel', but this ViewDataDictionary
>   instance requires a model item of type 'FreightPush.Core.Container'.*

Here is what I do know so far based on some very extensive internet research on this matter:

1. I can confirm that I am NOT establishing a model on my _layout
   page.
2. I know that Containers is an IENumerable and that the model of my _Summary page is a single Container, and I have seen several people on online forums point this out to be the most common mistake. HOWEVER, isn't that the purpose of the foreach loop, and its declared variable container? On my interactive debugger container works perfectly, and all the relevant fields populate from my SQL DB.
3. If I have understood what I have researched properly, then from what I gather the real culprit here is that the viewdatadictionary is shared among the views. However I can't find anywhere on the internet that shows me the proper syntax for passing view-data as a parameter and intellisense does not help. Is it even possible to fix the issue with a view-data parameter?

Thanks guys so much for all your help! This website is making the world a better place one amateur engineer at a time!

Comment: It work well when I only change it to `<partial name="_Summary" model="container" />` without `@`...

Comment: Thank you Xing. I have been staring at this same code for two days and I cannot believe I did not see that typo. That was EXACTLY the problem and you sir are a gentleman and a scholar. Just to add to this thread something a bit useful for future google searches related to the topic:
1) When you get tunnel vision, you will miss dumb mistakes
2) <partial> html tag helper has no issues at all passing a model, and once the error stated the issue was with the model the syntax of that line of code should have been my obvious suspect. 

thanks again Xing